# taking input and creating an array from spaces, then if the in put is more then 6 characters long

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
word2 = ""
while True:
    minute = datetime.now().minute
    second = datetime.now().second
    hour = datetime.now().hour
    now = datetime.now()

    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
    
    if hour > 9 and hour < 23 : 
        if (minute == 4 or minute == 30) and second == 0:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print(current_time)
        else:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            file = '.\data.txt'
            info = open(file,"r")
            word1 = info.read()
            info.close()
            if word1 != word2 : 
                backuptime = current_time
                n = 6   # every 2 characters
                split_string = [word1[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(word1), n)]
                for I in split_string:
                    print(I)
                    time.sleep(1)   
                word2 = word1
                time.sleep(8)
                print(backuptime)
```

I have the above script part,

i'm trying to figure out a way so it takes the input of the .\data.txt file, then for every word in the file it puts it in to an array, if the word is more than 6 characters long to split it down i.e. "welcome home" = "welcom","e", "home".

Comment: This executes whenever it runs, *except* when it's 4:30 past the hour exactly. I think you got that backwards. What is `word2` initially? Why are you comparing the next word to the previous one - are you also trying to prevent duplicates or something like that? What exactly is your question - your code does something that seems related to what you've written about (and some other stuff), but what exactly is the problem or question here?

Comment: sorry i uploaded the full test code i'm trying to get working, 
so between 9am and 23pm it will run the code,  at any point during the day the time has a 04 minute or 30 minute it will print the time, 
what i want to do that i have no idea how to do, is instead of "n=6"
then the split string.
I want it to read a text file that can change but as an example it could contain "hello world something something" 
I want it to print hello wait 8 seconds then print world wait 8 then split "something" to "somethi" 8... "ng" 
it's part of a display project that has 6 segments. how would i do that?